# Apply style to element when click outside of directive attribute element in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, svg

I have svg items that highlights their corresponding path when user click on them or hover them.

I'm using Directives to detect `onEnter` `onLeave` and `Click` events.

Its working fine when I hover ( I highlight ) then when I leave the element (I Play down )

Then When I click also the path is highlighted (

Actually what's happen is when I click elsewhere the Highlight stays.

What I can't do so is when I click on the rest of the screen I would like that the Highlight disappear.

Here's my directive logic

```
export class HighlightDirective {
  constructor(private renderer:Renderer2 , private el: ElementRef) {}
  clicked=false
  @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
    this.changeOpacity(1);
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
    if (!this.clicked) {
      this.changeOpacity(0);
    }
  }
  @HostListener('click') click() {
    this.changeOpacity(1);
    this.clicked = true;
  }
  changeOpacity(opacity: number) {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement.nextSibling, 'opacity', opacity);
  }

}
```

And here's a part of the SVG with the Highlight attribute tag

```
 <g id="b1" transform="translate(-885 -562)">
    <g id="b1select">
      <ellipse id="Ellipse_1" data-name="Ellipse 1" cx="5.3" cy="5.3" rx="5.3" ry="5.3" transform="translate(1309.17 932.12)" fill="none" stroke="#b18802" stroke-width="1"/>
      <text id="B1-2" data-name="B1" transform="translate(1310.67 939.62)" fill="#b18802" font-size="6" font-family="ArialMT, Arial"><tspan x="0" y="0">B1</tspan></text>
    </g>
    <rect appHighlight (click)="openDialog($event)" id="container" width="12" height="11" transform="translate(1308.67 931.62)" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0)"/>
    <path id="b1-3" data-name="b1" d="M1093.763,1595.658v-82.417s5-14.987-18.452-16.644-40.9,2.386-54.093-11.537-132.873-159.193-132.873-159.193-6.456-10.249-24.986-14.661-9.858-17.907-4.728-25.235,39.039-47.23,39.039-47.23" transform="translate(208.67 -656.38)" fill="none" stroke="#efcf2f" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2"/>
  </g>
```

Here's an example on [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-directivehover?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.scroll);
```

What I have used is that whenever mousedown event fires removeListner remove scroll event. Which we added before using addEventListner() . this.scroll is your defined event to do what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry, I donc get what you want to do

Comment: See this stackblitz link. what i have done here is clicking button 'click me' first. then menu context is open. then when you click outside of menu anywhere in the document, then menu will close and your style-class related condition is loaded. here I used [ngClass] and loaded .css class conditionally.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fxjxzv .

Comment: Thanks , it's a working solution so I'll accept it, What would is the handle the click inside the custom directive